# Unable to properly add Mingw-w64 to Path on Windows 8.1

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, path

I am learning C, but I am having trouble following the directions in properly configuring the [VSCode C/C++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) extension. Therefore, I have decided to create a Stack Overflow account and ask this question.

On step 4.4 of this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw), I am asked to add `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin` to the Path environment variable. Further, I am supposed to click "New", but I do not see any such button. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpyYU.png).

Here are the contents of the Path variable, before I tried editing it myself:

`C:\Users\eric\AppData\Local\Mu\bin;C:\Users\eric\introcs\j3d\bin;C:\Users\eric\introcs\bin;C:\Users\eric\introcs\java\bin;C:\Users\eric\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools`

On a related note, I would like to be able to compile and run C in VSCode, but I am yet to even compile it properly.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBpO9.png) showing the commands not working.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iru4u.png) after I restarted cmd.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqiDP.png) after I restarted my computer.

Here are the [contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnl2I.png) of C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWHzr.png) after I changed it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 shows the path entries as a list you can edit. That's where the "New" button comes into play. But that's just a convenience. Fundamentally, you are being instructed to append

`C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin`

to the list to get

`C:\Users\eric\AppData\Local\Mu\bin;C:\Users\eric\introcs\j3d\bin;C:\Users\eric\introcs\bin;C:\Users\eric\introcs\java\bin;C:\Users\eric\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin`

Comment: I just tried that. Unfortunately, it did not work. I have added a screenshot showing this. Are there different commands I should run?

Comment: 1) Did you start the console after making the change?  (This is possibly required).  2) What's the output of `echo %PATH%`?

Comment: I have edited it to show that. I also ran ```path```, because I know that does something similar.

Comment: As you say, the PATH didn't change. Maybe changes to the the system path is only effective after a reboot? You could either try that or changing the path for your user instead. (No real harm in changing both if you want to avoid rebooting, but want to affect other users)

Comment: How would I change the user path? I know that on one of the screenshots there is a "path" variable under the user variables, but that is an artifact of Lua installation. Also, does a reboot hunt down programs to put in the PATH variable, or is it just saved and edited after it is inevitably gets corrupted?

Comment: Re "*that is an artifact of Lua installation*", No, as you saw in the console, the path from the top box is appended to the path from the bottom box.

Comment: Environment vars are passed down from parent to child. If the parent process doesn't have the change, it won't pass it down to your console when you create it. Rebooting just ensures that all processes have the change. It's the nuclear option.

Comment: Reboot complete. Unfortunately, it still is not working. Should I should reinstall Mingw-w64, or will that interfere with what we have done? Also, Stack Overflow recommends that I move this discussion to chat, but I have insufficient reputation.

Comment: Does `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin` exist?

Comment: I actually forgot to check. Yes, there is. Thank you for your continued support!

Comment: If I try running any of the executables, it creates a dialog box that immediately disappears. ```x86_64-w64-mingw32-c++.exe``` and ```x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe``` looked promising, but to no avail.

Comment: Ah, so it's not working cause the path wasn't updated. Something tells me you didn't actually change the path in settings (in the dialog you first showed) /// Re "*it creates a dialog box that immediately disappears*", Normal.

Comment: I just did it again, but it did not work. I agree, it seems very strange.

Comment: I'm just going to reinstall.

Comment: eh? The install is correct. It's your path you haven't changed yet. You need to change your path to include the compiler

Comment: Ok. I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the variable to the system path correctly and restart no matter the problem that should work.